# Loop by number of Columns in CSV upload Coldfusion

Tags: loops, csv, coldfusion, upload

I'm customizing a CSV uploader to allow for column mapping. I've got a function that parses it into an Array, then I'm looping through it to generate select boxes with the uploaded file column names to map to existing column names in the corresponding table in my DB.

I can get the select drop downs to populate with the column names, but I can't figure out how to loop through the amount of columns in the uploaded file to limit the total amount of select dropdowns.

Function after it's parsed:

```
<!--- Get Value from Array based on Column Name --->
<cffunction name="ValByColName" access="public" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="ColName"type="string" required="true" default=""/>
    <cfargument name="DataArray" type="array" required="true" default=""/>
    <cfset findValue = keyArray.indexOf(#ColName#) + 1>
    <cfreturn(#DataArray[findValue]#) /> 
</cffunction>
```

LOOP:

```
<!--- Set Uploaded file to Array --->
                <cfset arrCSV = CSVToArray(CSVFilePath = #form.UploadedFile#,Delimiter = ",",Qualifier = """") />
                <!--- Create Key array from column names --->
                <cfset keyArray = ArrayNew(1)>
                <cfloop from="1" to="#DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE" index="t">
                    <!--- Variable Headers --->
                    <cfif Len(form.UploadedFile) GTE 5>
                        <cftry>

                            <select name="HeaderID" class="search" id="Header">
                            <option selected value="">--- Headers Uploaded ---</option>
                            <cfoutput>
                            <cfloop from="1" to="1" index="i">

                                <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrCSV[i])#" index="j">

                                     <option name="HeaderID" value="#j#">#arrCSV[i][j]#</option>

                                </cfloop>
                            </cfloop>
                            </cfoutput>
                            </select> =
                    </cftry> 

                    </cfif>
                    <cfquery name="clientsCols" datasource="#request.dsn#">
                        select Column_name 
                        from Information_schema.columns 
                        where Table_name like 'Clients'
                    </cfquery>
                    <!--- Constants--->
                    <cfif Len(form.UploadedFile) GTE 5>
                        <cftry>
                            <select name="ColumnID" class="search" id="Column">
                            <option selected value="">--- Headers Clients ---</option>
                            <cfoutput>
                                <cfloop query="clientsCols">
                                <option name="ColumnID" value="#Column_name#">#Column_name#</option>
                                </cfloop>
                            </cfoutput>
                            </select><br /><br />
                    </cftry> 

                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
```

Comment: (Edit) *how to loop through the amount of columns .. to limit the total amount of select dropdowns* If you have an array of the data/headers, you can use `arrayLen` to get the total number of columns. That said .. your loop code looks more bulky/complex than is necessary. What is an example of your array data/headers and what should the form should look like?

Comment: I always preferred using cfhttp and working with a query object for stuff like this. That's just me though.

Comment: If the file is well formed, and web accessible, `cfhttp` is an option (though it can sometimes be a little picky about what it will parse). But the question of creating a simple column mapper still stands. Whichever method is used to parse the csv, the form code should be simpler than the loop above ..

Comment: RE: `keyArray.indexOf( ColName )` .. As an side be very careful using undocumented methods like `indexOf`. Unlike most CF functions, [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) is both case *and* data type sensitive. So unless you fully understand the nuances, it can lead to some unexpected results .. For CF9+, I would recommend using [`ArrayFind/FindNoCase`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSF642CCBE-FB8B-4376-956B-BD1E55C10FF9.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for all of the reply's. It was staring me in the face, and Leigh , you were right on. I had the loops set up wrong and was able to add from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrCSV[1])#" index="t"> on the first loop, and I got my desired result. Now I need to add the mapped imported items to an insert query. Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveOntologic - You should post the final code as an answer, so it is easier to find than sifting through the comments.

Comment: @SteveOntologic - Instead of updating your question with the solution, add it as a new answer and then accept it. It will be easier for others to find that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare this to the original just above, you will see that using `cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrCSV[1])#" index="t"` got me exactly what I needed (5th line down in solution). After upload, the amount of select box pairs is the number of column headers in the uploaded file.

Thanks for everybody's responses.

```
<!--- Set Uploaded file to Array --->
<cfset arrCSV = CSVToArray(CSVFilePath = #form.UploadedFile#,Delimiter = ",",Qualifier = """") />
<!--- Create Key array from column names --->
<cfset keyArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrCSV[1])#" index="t">
    <!--- Variable Headers --->
    <cfif Len(form.UploadedFile) GTE 5>
        <select name="HeaderID" class="search" id="Header">
            <option selected value="">--- Headers Uploaded ---</option>
            <cfoutput>
            <cfloop from="1" to="1" index="i">
                <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrCSV[i])#" index="j">
                    <option name="HeaderID#t#" value="#j#">#arrCSV[i][j]#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </cfloop>
            </cfoutput>
        </select> =
    </cfif>
    <!---Column Constants--->
    <select name="ColumnID" class="search" id="Column">
        <option selected value="">--- Headers Clients ---</option>
        <cfoutput>
        <cfloop query="clientsCols">
            <option name="ColumnID#T#" value="#Column_name#">#Column_name#</option>
        </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </select><br /><br />
</cfloop>
```